# WPML + Custom Post Type Permalinks

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, wpml

I need to achieve to have custom permalink structure for CPT "products" and also have the rewrite slug translated.

Here is the situation. I translate the "products" slug with WPML, works fine. But when I activate, configure and flush the rewrite rules using "Custom post type permalinks" plugin. Then it overrides the translated slug with default language. I have tried to modify the plugin for the custom permalinks to register rewrite rules with slug in different languages but it won't work.

What I want:

```
EN: ..en/products/%product-category%/%postname%
SK: ..sk/protukty/%product-category%/%postname%
```

What I get:

```
EN: ..en/products/%product-category%/%postname%
SK: ..sk/products/%product-category%/%postname%
```

Note: I have every time re-saved the settings to flush rewrite rules

Note: I know how to translate cpt slug with wpml. Please ommit answers like Go to translation settings,check the translate custom post type slug,... like most of people do in other answers. This question **is not** about translating slug, its about translating slug **when/with** custom post type permalinks plugin is activated.

Thank you